# Converting C++11 into equivalent C++98 code

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

I'd like to use C++11, but unfortunately, to ensure binary compatibility with some proprietary libraries, I have to make sure that the code can be built with compilers that only support C++98. Is there a way to convert some C++11 constructs (at least those that don't require standard library support) into their C++98 equivalents?

For example:

```
std::vector<int> v = ...;
for (auto &i : v)
    std::cout << i << ' ';
```

converted to

```
std::vector<int> v = ...;
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it) {
  int &i = *it;
  std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

or something like that.

Comment: You have 10k and don't know that tool recommendation questions are off-topic? ;0

Comment: OK, I reformulate the question

Comment: Never understood these arbitrary rules on SO

Comment: They are not arbitrary. You can find lots of discussions and arguments on meta.... And what's more you can even participate...

Comment: And, sorry for nitpicking but "is there a way" is *too broad* on the other hand...

Comment: Well, yeah, perhaps. Sorry, can't help it :)

Comment: @vitaut: I suspect there's trivial code in C++11 which cannot be translated to trivial C++98, especially with `nothrow`, varargs, rvalues, `decltype`, unrestricted unions, threading...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to create a source-to-source compiler using [LibTooling](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html) (part of the Clang project, it's specifically meant for writing high-level tools) doing this conversion automatically and properly (as opposed to writing your own parser in Perl, for example).

Note that there are C++11/14 constructs which cannot be as easily transformed to C++98/03 code as a ranged for-loop. Variadic templates, amongst others, come to mind.

Comment: I hoped someone already wrote such tool on top of Clang =)

Comment: Not as far as I know. But it shouldn't be too hard for the simple conversions.

Comment: llvm also has a C++ backend.  Use -march=cpp to try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool which can convert to C.
If your problem is just compiler support, and you don't need very readable output, that could be enough.

https://www.edg.com/index.php?location=c_frontend

https://www.edg.com/index.php?location=faq_q6_convert

P.S. You didn't ask for cheap :-)

Comment: Thanks. I knew about EDG frontend of course, but didn't know they have a converter to C.